# Is there a way to listen/react to clicks in a tab in Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a Teams app that shows personal tabs. Is there a way to get the event of clicking in the tab? Does that trigger/fires any event that we can get in the SDK (or through the manifest)?

I want to refresh some content when the tab is clicked, even if the user is already in clicked tab.

The users can navigate in the tab to different pages. I could put a "reload"/"back to home" inside the page, but in my test with the users they are already clicking in the tab itself expecting to it reload the first page again (which is a bit strange considering that browsers don't work like this).

Example: We have list of news from the organization, the user can click on them to open and see the details. From the details they can navigate to see another thing. Them I find that they try to click on the tab name to go back to first page with reloaded news.

Comment: The tab is just a web page that you host yourself anyway, so you could do a periodic refresh behind the scenes perhaps, especially if the user is already in the tab - would that be applicable?

Comment: Not really in my case, I'm afraid, but I can see that working in other scenarios. Just edited the question to reflect that. The users are looking at it as if they were "restarting the app to the home page".

Comment: oh, I don't mean making a button for the user, I mean doing it programmatically, so the user doesn't have to do anything and it just "magically" keeps itself up to date. This site is an example - https://www.xe.com/ , and they happen to have a counter on the bottom to show how many seconds are left between refreshes, but you don't need to have that on the page. This is just an idea of course

Comment: separate to that, to my recollection, every time the user clicks away and comes back to your tab, it will do a fresh load anyway, I think. So it's really on when they are "on" the tab already that might be a concern?

Comment: Exactly, just edited the question again. Thanks for making it better through your comments. :)
The issue is that they feel intuitive to click on the tab to go back to the "homepage" of the tab with reloaded items while they are inside the tab itself, so they asked if I could make that work. I am not sure if that is common thinking for other users, maybe that would qualify as an UX improvement to Teams itself.

Comment: ahh, now I understand better - thanks for updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Based on the updated question, I'm giving a full answer properly here]
So, no "refresh" will fire simply by the user clicking the name of the tab itself, if they're already inside there. You'd need to either train/encourage the users to click the actual Refresh button that Teams provides alongside the tabs, or handle this within your tab itself.

Remember, once the user is inside your tab, you completely control the experience, so the web page can do whatever you want it to do. As an example, if you add a "back" button on the news items themselves, you could hook into it's event handler, and when they click that, do a "refresh" to your api to retrieve latest news items. As an alternative, to provide a really fluid experience, you could be calling back to the api on a regular periodic basis (e.g. every minute) via javascript, update however your news items are stored (e.g. update the html container) so that when they click "Back", the latest news is already loaded. Something like [signalr](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr) could be another option, to "push" new articles to the tab directly.

Hopefully one of those options will work